# Blender 3D objects keep intersecting when trying to position

Tags: blender, modeling, 3d-model

So I am trying to make a 3D model of a chug jug, it is my first commission, and when I try to position the chug jug with the blue object that represents the drink, they keep on intersecting. I know there is a setting somewhere that disables objects intersecting each other when modeling but I forgot where. Also the liquid inside the chug jug has to be there too because my client says he’s going to 3D print the parts and so he needs the bottle and drink to be different colors.

Answer (score 0):

Object intersections is something that is only used by physics simulations or game engines where the computer is calculating new positions of objects.

When you are modeling in a 3D program you are manually defining the surface of the object. While not really intersection testing, modeling tools offer snapping and alignment options to assist you in positioning the multiple surfaces near each other.

Blender has several [snapping options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html) that will align to other vertices or surfaces. Note that to create parts that will be 3D printed and fit together, you should consider modeling with a small gap between the two surfaces.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have fixed my blender model and it looks better.